# aws s3 sync --recursive not working in windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, cmd

I am using AWS-CLI in windows cmd and run AWS s3 sync command but it does not work with --recursive, it shows unknown options: --recursive

> > aws s3 sync --recursive localpath s3://bucket-name
> >
> > python --version   python 3.6.5
> >
> > aws --version aws-cli/1.15.38 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2012Server botocore/1.10.38

Please help

Comment: Maybe because there's no `--recursive` parameter, considering the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Answer (score 27):

The [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command is already recursive, so there is no need for a recursive option, and there isn't one:

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated
>   files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates
>   folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

In addition the `sync` command only copies things that don't already exist on the destination. If you point to a folder it will recursively sync everything inside that doesn't already exist on your target destination. This is different then the [`aws s3 cp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command. The `cp` command copies whatever you tell it to, regardless of it it already exists on the target. The `cp` command takes a `--recursive` option for recursively copying folders.